# Adobe CQ html5smartimage image file type restriction

Tags: aem

I am trying to restrict the file type that can be set as a background image in my component. I have also bmp images in my DAM, but I need to use only jpg and png and forbid bmp.

This is the fragment of my dialog.xml

```
<background
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    cropParameter=""
    ddGroups="[media]"
    fieldLabel="background image field"
    fileNameParameter="./background/fileName"
    fileReferenceParameter="./background/fileReference"
    height="{Long}200"
    name="./background/file"
    rotateParameter=""
    title="background"
    width="{Long}200"
    xtype="html5smartimage"/>
```

And what I have tried to use is

```
requestSuffix=".img.png"
```

and

```
ddAccept="[image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/bmp,image/png,image/gif]"
```

But neither worked. Is there any way to set such restrictions?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the wrong property, you should use mimeTypes instead.

```
<image
           jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
           ..
           ..
            mimeTypes=".jpeg"
            name="./file"
            requestSuffix="/image.img.png"
            title="Image"
            xtype="html5smartimage" />
```

Uses comma to add more types of files. See the documention for detail.
[html5smartimage description](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.html5.form.SmartImage)

Comment: The doc says it is "MIME types allowed for uploading (each separated by a semicolon; wildcard * is allowed; for example: "*.*" or "*.jpg;*.gif;*.png". Defaults to "*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png"." I tried that property but with no luck. The ddAccept is for "MIME type definition of files that are allowed for referencing using drag & drop (defaults to "image/")" and seems to be more suitable. Please correct me if I am wrong